# Python: child process to update global resources used by parent

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I need to create a child process in my main app that update a dict every n seconds.

This dictionary will be used by the parent process as a global variable.

Here is a pseudo-code of what I am trying to do:

```py
dict_ = {"a":12,"b":23}


def child_process()
    global dict_
    while True:
       # update dict_
       time.sleep(n)

def parent_process():
    global dict_
    # use dict_ WITHOUT MODIFYING IT

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # 1- run child process 
    # 2- run parent process
```

I found a lot about multiprocessing but I steel can't figure out how I can do this.

Comment: What do you mean without modifying it? Just don't modify it?

Comment: Just read `a` and `b` but without modifying the dict... So `child_process` will modify the dict_ and `parent_process` will just use this fresh data

Comment: [Google before asking](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value)

Comment: @Natecat already googled my friend ;) otherwise I will not be here asking for help. With no offense please avoid useless comments next time !

Comment: it is not pseudo code, it doesn't do what you intend to. your code doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

We generally use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) in multiprocessing or threading to share data or results. However, for python constructs like `list` and `dict` [Managers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) are used. Please find your requirement here:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

dict_ = Manager().dict({"a":12,"b":23})

def child_process(_dict):
    while _dict['b'] < 30:
        _dict['b'] += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc = Process(target=child_process, args=(dict_,))
    proc.start()
    # Here output printed is value from 23 to 30.
    # while proc.is_alive():
    #     print dict_.get("b")
    proc.join()
    print dict_.get("b")    # prints 30
```